# How to download multiple files using wget in linux and save them with custom name for each downloaded file

Tags: linux, input, filenames, wget

How to download multiple files using wget. Lets say i have a urls.txt containing several urls and i want to save them automatically with a custom filename for each file. How to do this?

I tried downloading 1 by 1 with this format "wget -c url1 -O filename1" successfully and now i want to try do batch download.

Answer (score 1):

You might take look at [`xargs`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) command, you would need to prepare file with arguments for each `wget` call, lets say it is named `download.txt` and

```
-O file1.html https://www.example.com
-O file2.html https://www.duckduckgo.com
```

and then use it as follows

```
cat download.txt | xargs wget -c
```

which is equivalent to doing

```
wget -c -O file1.html https://www.example.com
wget -c -O file2.html https://www.duckduckgo.com
```

Comment: Thank you @Daweo I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the input file and a loop:

```
for i in `cat urls.txt`; do wget $i -O filename-$i; done
```

Comment: Thank you @Max888 can you explain it like im 6 years old please I am new to this "loop"

Comment: so.. for every line in urls.txt, perform a wget statement.  you can paste that line into the terminal and it will work (assuming you have urls.txt in place)

Comment: so is there any format required for the contents of my urls.txt? how can i have custom filename for each download?

Comment: Let say i want to save url1 as This-is-a-zipfile.zip, url2 as Goodmorning.mp4, url3 as Interview.mp3 how?